# ¿Cómo puedo descompactar un tar.gz indicando la ruta donde guardarlo?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, tar

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio que consiste en lo siguiente:

> Inicialmente debe introducirse el nombre de un fichero o directorio.
>
> Luego, hay que indicar si es un fichero o un directorio, o no existe.
>
> 1. indique si es un fichero o un directorio, o no existe.
> 2. Si es un fichero y existe, indicar su ruta y:
>
>    a) Preguntar si muestro el contenido del fichero.
>
>    b) Preguntar si se quiere compactar y comprimir, preguntar la ruta
>      donde se va a guardad.
> 3. Si es un directorio y existe indicar su ruta y preguntar si se quiere compactar y comprimir. Se ha de preguntar la ruta donde se va a
>      guardar el comprimido.
> 4. Si no es un fichero ni directorio, que pregunte si quiere crear uno u otro, después de lo que decida el usuario y de darle dos
>      opciones:
>
>    a) Opción de editar el fichero.
>
>    b) Opción de compactar y comprimir (Nota: Personal aparte de el
>      ejercicio Yo lo hice para los dos casos sea fichero o directorio).
> 5. Si se introduce un fichero o directorio ya comprimido y/o compactado (xxxx.tar.gz), que dé la opción de
>      descompactar/descomprimir, también he de pedir la ruta donde se va ha
>      extraer.
> 6. Salida.

No tengo ni idea de cómo hacer el apartado 5.

---

Este es mi código:

```
#!/bin/bash
#reset

read -p "Introduce el nombre del fichero o directorio: " nombre;
buscador=$(find /home/ -name "$nombre");
auxiliar=$(find /home/ -name "$nombre" | wc -l); #Sin este auxiliar el programa se cree que hay un directorio aunque no exista.
aux_desc=$(find /home/ -name "*.tar.gz");
if [ $auxiliar == 1 ] && [ $nombre != $aux_desc ];
then
    if [ -d $buscador ];
    then
        echo 'Es un directorio';
        echo "La ruta de este es: $buscador";
        echo "Quieres compactar y comprimir.";
        echo -e "1.Para Si.\n2.Para No.";
        read -p "Introduce tu opcion (default 2): " opcion;
        if [ -z opcion ];
        then
            opcion=2;
        fi
        case $opcion in
        1)  read -p "Indique la ruta donde se va a guardar el comprimido: " ruta_comprimido;
            tar czf $buscador.tar.gz $buscador;
            buscador_tar=$(find /home/ -name "$nombre.tar.gz");
            mv $buscador_tar $ruta_comprimido;
            echo "Listo.";;
        2)  echo "Hasta pronto!!";;
        *)  echo "La opcion no es valida.";;
        esac
    elif [ -f $buscador ];
    then
        echo 'Es un fichero';
        echo "La ruta de este es: $buscador";
        echo 'A continuacion tus opciones';
        echo -e '1-Para mostrar el contenido.\n2-Para compactar y comprimir.';
        read -p "Introduce tu opcion 1 o 2 (default 1): " opcion;
        if [ -z $opcion ]; #Comprueba si el buffer esta vacio o no.
        then
            let opcion=1;
        fi
        case $opcion in
        1)  echo "El contenido del fichero es el siguiente: ";
            cat $buscador;
            echo "Listo.";;
        2)  read -p "Indique la ruta donde se va a guardar el comprimido: " ruta_comprimido;
            tar czf $buscador.tar.gz $buscador;
            buscador_tar=$(find /home/ -name "$nombre.tar.gz");
            mv $buscador_tar $ruta_comprimido;
            echo "Listo.";; #Muevo el comprimido en la ruta a compripir.
        *) echo "Esa opcion no es valida.";;
        esac
    fi
elif [ $nombre == $aux_desc ];
then
    echo 'Has introducido un elemento ya compactado y comprimido';
    echo 'Lo descompactare pero primero.';
    read -p "Indique la ruta donde se va a extraer: " ruta_extraer;
            tar xzf $buscador;
            buscador_extraer=$(find /home/ -name "$nombre");
            mv $buscador_extraer $ruta_extraer;
            echo "Listo."
else
echo 'El fichero o directorio no exite';
echo 'Quieres crearlo?';
echo -e "1.Para Si.\n2.Para No.";
read -p "Introduce tu opcion: " opcion;
if [ $opcion == 1 ];
then
    echo 'Quieres que sea un fichero o un directorio?';
    echo -e "1.Para ficchero\n2.Para directorio.";
    read -p "Introduce tu opcion: " opcion;
    case $opcion in
    1)  touch $nombre;
        echo 'Quieres editar el fichero?'
        echo -e "1.Para Si.\n2.Para No.";
        read -p "Introduce tu opcion: " opc;
        case $opc in
            1) nano $nombre;;
            2) 'Vale.';;
            *) echo 'Esa opcion no exise adios.';;
        esac
        echo 'Quieres compactar y comprimirlo?';
        echo -e "1.Para Si.\n2.Para No.";
        read -p "Introduce tu opcion: " opc;
        case $opc in
            1)  read -p "Indique la ruta donde se va a guardar el comprimido: " ruta_comprimido;
                tar czf $nombre.tar.gz $nombre;
                buscador_tar=$(find /home/ -name "$nombre.tar.gz");
                mv $buscador_tar $ruta_comprimido;
                echo "Listo.";;
            2)  echo 'Vale.';;
            *) echo 'Esa opcion no existe adios.';;
        esac
    ;;
    2)  mkdir $nombre
        read -p "Indique la ruta donde se va a guardar el comprimido: " ruta_comprimido;
        tar czf $nombre.tar.gz $nombre;
        buscador_tar=$(find /home/ -name "$nombre.tar.gz");
        mv $buscador_tar $ruta_comprimido;
        echo "Listo."
    ;;
    *)  echo 'Esa opcion no existe adios.';;
    esac
else
    echo 'Adios.'
fi
fi
```

Comment: el comando para descomprimir un archivo *.tar.gz es: tar -xzf archivo.tar.gz, fijate en el man del comando tar las opciones.

Comment: gracias pero todavía no ce como identificar si el usuario introduce un archivo tar ejemplo: prueba.txt.tar.gz quiero saber como poder identificar eso para poder descomprimirlo.

Comment: Pones muchísimo código, pero tu duda está centrada en una parte específica. Sería bueno tener un [mcve] para centrarte en lo importante y dejar de lado el resto.

Comment: Lo estuve comentando con el profesor y le pregunte si podía preguntarle al usuario antes de que ingrese el nombre de algo si es un fichero o archivo, o un archivo.tar.gz y dependiendo de la opción que elija hago algo el programa que ya tengo escrito o salto directamente a descomprimir. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar una [expansión de shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) como: `extension="${fullfilename##*.}"` y obtener la extensión del archivo `fullfilename`, sin embargo, el problema es que si la misma fuera `tar.gz` solo obtendrás `gz`, por lo que me parece que la mejor alternativa es usar la funcionalidad de expresiones regulares del `case` de la siguiente forma:

```
#!/bin/bash
fullfilename="/home/user/archivo.tar.gz"

case "$fullfilename" in
        *.tar.gz) echo "Es un archivo tar comprimido con gzip" ;;
        *.tar.bz2) echo "Es un archivo tar comprimido con bzip" ;;
esac
```

Por último, tal como bien indica @fedorqui, a la hora de descomprimir el `tar` en un directorio particular puedes hacer:

```
tar -xvzf $fullfilename -C $otuputfolder
```

Ver [manual del tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html)

Comment: ¡Buena idea! Podrías añadir también la parte de cómo indicar el directorio donde guardarlo, que es `-C` o `--directory`, tal y como vimos en [Unix Untar a File Into a Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21623670/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui, gracias, tomo tu sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Yo recomendaría jugar con `file` para obtener el mymetype del archivo `application/gzip application/x-tar application/x-bzip2` y determinar el formato de compresión de manera más precisa evitando nombres de archivo incorrectos.